How to play custom audio using SIP.js?
I need to play custom audios during calls from the browser to some phone number in my app. We have set up an Asterisk server with a WebRTC connection.
Now I can establish a connection between browsers and have a conversation (caller and callee can hear and talk to each other).
Here is my React.js component for establishing connections:
import { AppLayout } from '@/components/layout';
import Head from 'next/head';
import {
    Invitation,
    InvitationAcceptOptions,
    Inviter,
    Message,
    Registerer,
    Session,
    SessionState,
    URI,
    UserAgent,
    UserAgentOptions,
    Web,
} from 'sip.js';
import { Button } from '@/components/common';
import { useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useLocalStorage } from '@/hooks/useLocalStorage';
import { WebAudioSessionDescriptionHandler } from 'sip.js/lib/platform/web';

CallInProgressV2Page.requireAuth = true;

const pass = 'password';
const wsServer = 'wss://correct.domain-here.com:8089/ws';
const audioUrl =
    'some audio URL here.mp3';

export default function CallInProgressV2Page() {
    const myMediaStreamRef = useRef<MediaStream>(new MediaStream());
    const myMediaStreamFactory: Web.MediaStreamFactory = async (
        constraints: MediaStreamConstraints,
        sessionDescriptionHandler: Web.SessionDescriptionHandler
    ): Promise<MediaStream> => {
        const microphoneStream =
            await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        myMediaStreamRef.current = microphoneStream;
        return myMediaStreamRef.current;
    };

    const mySessionDescriptionHandlerFactory: Web.SessionDescriptionHandlerFactory =
        Web.defaultSessionDescriptionHandlerFactory(myMediaStreamFactory);

    const audioCtxRef = useRef<AudioContext>(new AudioContext());
    const [extension, setExtension] = useLocalStorage('extension', '');
    const [extensionTarget, setExtensionTarget] = useLocalStorage(
        'extension_target',
        ''
    );
    const sipUri = `${extension}@correct-domain.here`;
    const userAgentRef = useRef<UserAgent | null>(null);
    const registererRef = useRef<Registerer | null>(null);
    const inviterRef = useRef<Inviter | null>(null);
    const [generalState, setGeneralState] = useState<any>({
        sessionState: 'NOT_STARTED',
        inviterState: 'INITIAL',
        isInitiated: false,
        isLocalMuted: false,
        isRemoteMuted: false,
    });
    const remoteStreamRef = useRef<MediaStream | null>(null);
    const currentSessionRef = useRef<Session | null>(null);

    function assignStream(stream: MediaStream, element: HTMLMediaElement): void {
        element.autoplay = true;
        element.srcObject = stream;

        element.play().catch((error: Error) => {
            console.error('Failed to play media');
            console.error(error);
        });

        stream.onaddtrack = (): void => {
            element.load();
            element.play().catch((error: Error) => {
                console.error('Failed to play remote media on add track');
                console.error(error);
            });
        };

        stream.onremovetrack = (): void => {
            element.load();
            element.play().catch((error: Error) => {
                console.error('Failed to play remote media on remove track');
                console.error(error);
            });
        };
    }

    const onInvite = async (invitation: Invitation) => {
        const incomingSession = invitation;
        incomingSession.stateChange.addListener((newState: SessionState) => {
            switch (newState) {
                case SessionState.Initial:
                    setGeneralState({
                        ...generalState,
                        sessionState: 'INITIAL',
                    });
                    break;
                case SessionState.Establishing:
                    setGeneralState({
                        ...generalState,
                        sessionState: 'ESTABLISHING',
                    });
                    break;
                case SessionState.Established:
                    setGeneralState({
                        ...generalState,
                        sessionState: 'ESTABLISHED',
                    });
                    const remoteHTMLMediaElement = document.getElementById(
                        'remoteMediaElement'
                    ) as HTMLAudioElement;
                    const sessionDescriptionHandler =
                        incomingSession.sessionDescriptionHandler;
                    if (
                        !sessionDescriptionHandler ||
                        !(
                            sessionDescriptionHandler instanceof Web.SessionDescriptionHandler
                        )
                    ) {
                        throw new Error('Invalid session description handler.');
                    }
                    if (remoteHTMLMediaElement) {
                        assignStream(
                            sessionDescriptionHandler.remoteMediaStream,
                            remoteHTMLMediaElement
                        );
                    }
                    break;
                case SessionState.Terminated:
                    setGeneralState({
                        ...generalState,
                        sessionState: 'TERMINATED',
                    });
                    break;
                case SessionState.Terminating:
                    setGeneralState({
                        ...generalState,
                        sessionState: 'TERMINATING',
                    });
                    break;
            }
        });
        const options: InvitationAcceptOptions = {
            sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions: {
                constraints: {
                    audio: true,
                    video: false,
                },
            },
        };
        await invitation.accept(options);
    };

    const onConnect = async () => {
        console.log('%c CONNECTED', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    };

    const onMessage = async (message: Message) => {
        console.log('MESSAGE');
        console.log(message);
    };

    const onRegister = async (data: any) => {
        console.log('%c REGISTER', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
        console.log(data);
    };

    const userAgentOptions: UserAgentOptions = {
        authorizationPassword: pass,
        authorizationUsername: extension,
        sessionDescriptionHandlerFactory: mySessionDescriptionHandlerFactory,
        transportOptions: {
            server: wsServer,
        },
        delegate: {
            onInvite,
            onConnect,
            onMessage,
            onRegister,
        },
        uri: UserAgent.makeURI(`sip:${sipUri}`),
    };

    const init = async () => {
        userAgentRef.current = new UserAgent(userAgentOptions);
        registererRef.current = new Registerer(userAgentRef.current);
        await userAgentRef.current.start();
        await registererRef.current.register();
        setGeneralState({
            ...generalState,
            isInitiated: true,
        });
        remoteStreamRef.current = new MediaStream();
    };

    const isCallInProgress = useMemo(() => {
        return (
            generalState.inviterState === 'ESTABLISHED' ||
            generalState.sessionState === 'ESTABLISHED'
        );
    }, [generalState]);

    const makeCall = async () => {
        if (!userAgentRef.current || !registererRef.current) {
            return;
        }

        const target = UserAgent.makeURI(
            `sip:${extensionTarget}@correct-domain.here`
        ) as URI;

        try {
            const localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
                video: false,
            });
            inviterRef.current = new Inviter(userAgentRef.current, target, {
                sessionDescriptionHandlerOptions: {
                    constraints: {
                        audio: true,
                        video: false,
                    },
                },
            });

            inviterRef.current.stateChange.addListener(
                async (state: SessionState) => {
                    switch (state) {
                        case SessionState.Initial:
                            setGeneralState({
                                ...generalState,
                                inviterState: 'INITIAL',
                            });
                            break;
                        case SessionState.Establishing:
                            setGeneralState({
                                ...generalState,
                                inviterState: 'ESTABLISHING',
                            });
                            break;
                        case SessionState.Established:
                            setGeneralState({
                                ...generalState,
                                inviterState: 'ESTABLISHED',
                            });
                            const remoteHTMLMediaElement = document.getElementById(
                                'remoteMediaElement'
                            ) as HTMLAudioElement;
                            const sessionDescriptionHandler = inviterRef.current
                                ?.sessionDescriptionHandler as WebAudioSessionDescriptionHandler;
                            const pc = sessionDescriptionHandler?.peerConnection;
                            pc?.getSenders().forEach((sender) => {});

                            if (
                                !sessionDescriptionHandler ||
                                !(
                                    sessionDescriptionHandler instanceof
                                    Web.SessionDescriptionHandler
                                )
                            ) {
                                throw new Error('Invalid session description handler.');
                            }
                            if (remoteHTMLMediaElement) {
                                assignStream(
                                    sessionDescriptionHandler.remoteMediaStream,
                                    remoteHTMLMediaElement
                                );
                            }
                            break;
                        case SessionState.Terminated:
                            setGeneralState({
                                ...generalState,
                                inviterState: 'TERMINATED',
                            });
                            break;
                        case SessionState.Terminating:
                            setGeneralState({
                                ...generalState,
                                inviterState: 'TERMINATING',
                            });
                            break;
                    }
                }
            );
            await inviterRef.current.invite();

            const sessionHandler = inviterRef.current
                .sessionDescriptionHandler as Web.SessionDescriptionHandler;
            if (localStream) {
                localStream
                    .getTracks()
                    .forEach(
                        (track) =>
                            sessionHandler.peerConnection?.addTrack(track, localStream)
                    );
            }

            await inviterRef.current.invite();
            currentSessionRef.current = inviterRef.current;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during call setup:', error);
        }
    };

    const hangUp = () => {
        if (!inviterRef.current) {
            return;
        }
        inviterRef.current?.bye();
        remoteStreamRef.current = null;

        inviterRef.current = null;
        currentSessionRef.current = null;
    };

    const loadAudio = async (): Promise<AudioBuffer> => {
        const audioResponse = await fetch(audioUrl);
        const audioBuffer = await audioResponse.arrayBuffer();
        const decodedData = await audioCtxRef.current.decodeAudioData(audioBuffer);
        return decodedData;
    };

    const test = async () => {
        try {
            const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
            const audioElement = new Audio(audioUrl);
            audioElement.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
            audioElement.onerror = (error: any) => {
                console.log(error);
            };
            audioElement.onended = () => {
                console.log('AUDIO ENDED');
            };
            audioElement.volume = 1;
            const audioSource = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
            const destination = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination();
            const microphoneSource = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(
                myMediaStreamRef.current
            );

            const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
            gainNode.gain.value = 0.8;

            microphoneSource.connect(gainNode).connect(destination);
            audioSource.connect(destination);

            const mixedStream = destination.stream;
            myMediaStreamRef.current = mixedStream;

            audioElement.oncanplaythrough = () => {
                audioElement.play();
            };
            audioElement.load();

            const sessionHandler = currentSessionRef.current
                ?.sessionDescriptionHandler as Web.SessionDescriptionHandler;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Active call V2</title>
            </Head>
            <AppLayout isComingSoon={false}>
                <div>call progress v2</div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Mutual media</div>
                        <audio src="" id="mutualMediaElement" controls></audio>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>Local media</div>
                        <audio src="" id="localMediaElement" controls></audio>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>remote media</div>
                        <audio src="" id="remoteMediaElement" controls></audio>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>audio</div>
                        <audio
                            src={audioUrl}
                            id={'audioElement'}
                            controls
                            preload={'auto'}
                        ></audio>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-2">
                    <label htmlFor="">My extension</label>
                    <input
                        className="rounded-lg border border-blue-600 px-2 py-1"
                        value={extension}
                        onChange={(e) => setExtension(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-2">
                    <label htmlFor="">Extension target</label>
                    <input
                        className="rounded-lg border border-blue-600 px-2 py-1"
                        value={extensionTarget}
                        onChange={(e) => setExtensionTarget(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-2">
                    <div>Extension: {extension}</div>
                    <div>Target extensions: {extensionTarget}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="mb-2">
                    <audio src={audioUrl} controls></audio>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div>{JSON.stringify(generalState, null, 2)}</div>
                <hr />
                <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                    {!generalState.isInitiated && (
                        <Button size={'sm'} onClick={init}>
                            Init
                        </Button>
                    )}
                    {!!extensionTarget && generalState.isInitiated && (
                        <Button size={'sm'} onClick={makeCall}>
                            Make call to target
                        </Button>
                    )}
                    {isCallInProgress && (
                        <Button onClick={hangUp} variant={'danger'} size={'sm'}>
                            End call
                        </Button>
                    )}
                    <Button onClick={test} variant={'info'}>
                        Test
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </AppLayout>
        </>
    );
}


I think but not sure function test might be somewhere close to what I need, audio on ended event is triggered after some time but I can't hear that audio and callee can't hear also. Don't have any clue how to achieve it.
Function loadAudio works as expected and returns AudioBuffer, also I am able to play my audio with following code (so link is correct)
const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
audio.play();

Please help me.
Browser microphone should be muted and only custom audios should be played.
